# SQL query - calculate number of days between days

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table which has columns

```
RowId        int    
MailSent     DateTime    
Acknowledged DateTime    
Name         varchar(100)
```

Datas as below,

```
ROWID  MAILSENT     ACKNOWLEDGED NAME    
1.     2016/01/01.   NULL.        A    
2.     NULL.         2016/01/10   A    
3.     2016/01/21.   NULL.        A    
4.     NULL.         2016/01/30.  A     
5.     2016/01/01.   Null.        B    
6.     Null.         2016/01/10   B
```

So the result I need is total days taken by users to acknowledge the mail.

Like for user A the answer should be  20days(10 +10) and for user B is 10days.

Please provide me query for calculating total days taken by users to acknowledge all mails.

Comment: which database are you using? Postgressql?

Comment: your question is not clear.  You mean total number (single number output) or a row per name with the total of days taken by this user to process all their mail?  Also when dealing with funky things like dates and timestamps you need to specify which db you are talking about.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Rob SqlServer 2012

Comment: @TabAlleman I didnt post this question for research purpose. Just wanted to know how to get total days taken to acknowledge a email userwise.

Comment: Check out the `lag()` function

Comment: I think the OP just doesn't know how to use a subquery yet. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
I used the lag() function to calculate days.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @startdate date = MailSent
DECLARE @enddate date = Acknowledged

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2);

MSDN LINK:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: MAILSENT, ACKNOWLEDGED columns wont b in same row

Comment: good point... although the answer is above he just has to make a select statement to get the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> select datediff(day, stuff.start, stuff.end) from (select
>   max(mailsent) as start, max(acknowledged) as end group by name) stuff